# How can i determine if statement in ruby

Tags: android, ruby

android always get me second condition even if first if is true. Whats im doing wrong?

```
def enter_credentials(user,password,*domain)
  if check_element_exists(" * id:'authDialogUserDomainEntry'")== true
    sleep 5
    enter_text(username_field, user)
    sleep 2
    enter_text(password_field, password)
    sleep 2
    enter_text(domain_field, domain)
    screenshot_embed
    sleep 3
    hide_soft_keyboard
    touch(authorize_button)
    sleep 10
  else
   sleep 5
    enter_text(username_field, user)
    sleep 2
    enter_text(password_field, password)
    sleep 4 
        hide_soft_keyboard
    sleep 4
   touch(authorize_button)
  end
end
```

Every time it gives me just second condition even if such element exist

Comment: what is `check_element_exists`? what gem are you using?

Comment: Is `check_element_exists(" * id:'authDialogUserDomainEntry'")` actually returning true ? have you tried printing the output..maybe you're missing something while calling that method ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using calabash-android and when i call just this method

```
check_element_exists(" * id:'authDialogUserDomainEntry'")
```

it always return me

```
irb(main):005:0> check_element_exists(" * id:'authDialogUserDomainEntry'")
nil
```

Answer (score 0):

`check_element_exists` returns nil if there's a match (otherwise it raises an error). 
If you want Boolean value use `element_exists` method.